# How to parse Nested Elements in Python using dexml

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse the following xml using dexml:

```
<ticketDetail>
        <ticketId>int</ticketId>
.....
      </ticketDetail>
      <participants>
        <ParticipantDetailExt>
          <participantId>int</participantId>
...
        </ParticipantDetailExt>
        <ParticipantDetailExt>
          <participantId>int</participantId>
...
        </ParticipantDetailExt>
      </participants>
```

My Models are as follows:

```
# Participant Class
class Participant(dexml.Model):
    class meta:
        tagname = "ParticipantDetailExt"

    participantId = fields.Integer(tagname='participantId')
...

# Ticket Class
class Ticket(dexml.Model):
    class meta:
        namespace = "Namespace Here"
        tagname = "ticketDetail"

    ticketId = fields.String(tagname='ticketId')
    ...
    participants = fields.List(Participant)
```

But while all the elements that are not nested parse correctly, the participants are not being parsed and loaded into the object structure.  How can you model this type of structure using dexml?

Here is sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import dexml
from dexml import fields

samplexml = """<ticketDetail>
    <ticketId>1</ticketId>
  <participants>
    <ParticipantDetailExt>
      <participantId>2</participantId>
    </ParticipantDetailExt>
    <ParticipantDetailExt>
      <participantId>3</participantId>
    </ParticipantDetailExt>
  </participants>
</ticketDetail>"""

class Participant(dexml.Model):
    class meta:
        tagname = "ParticipantDetailExt"

    participantId = fields.Integer(tagname='participantId')

class Ticket(dexml.Model):
    class meta:
        tagname = "ticketDetail"

    ticketId = fields.String(tagname='ticketId')
    participants = fields.List(Participant)


myTk = Ticket.parse(samplexml)
print(myTk.ticketId)
print(len(myTk.participants))

Output is:
1
0

Expected Output would be:
1
2
```

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please include all data required to run the program. Copy-paste your program along with the expected and actual output into your question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Shouldn't `</ticketDetail>` appear at the *end* of the XML?

Comment: Rob,  It does I neglected to copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `tagname` to your `List()`:

```
participants = fields.List(Participant, tagname="participants")
```

Sample program:

```
import dexml
from dexml import fields

# Participant Class
class Participant(dexml.Model):
    class meta:
        tagname = "ParticipantDetailExt"

    participantId = fields.Integer(tagname='participantId')


# Ticket Class
class Ticket(dexml.Model):
    class meta:
        #namespace = "Namespace Here"
        tagname = "ticketDetail"

    ticketId = fields.String(tagname='ticketId')
    participants = fields.List(Participant, tagname="participants")

t = Ticket.parse('''
<ticketDetail>
        <ticketId>int</ticketId>
      <participants>
        <ParticipantDetailExt>
          <participantId>42</participantId>
        </ParticipantDetailExt>
        <ParticipantDetailExt>
          <participantId>74</participantId>
        </ParticipantDetailExt>
      </participants>
      </ticketDetail>
''')

assert len(t.participants) == 2
```